# dynamically cast and invoke in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I am using a bit of Reflexion in my WebApp. What I am trying to do is invoke a method dynamically after doing type case - which is also not know at compile time

Here is the structure of my code:

```
            Controller (Interface with one method called 'execute()')
                   |
                   |
                  \|/
             BaseController (Abstract Class with 1 abstr method called 'execute()')
              /         \
             /          _\|
            /            GetCarController extends BaseController
          |/_
         AddCarController extends BaseController
```

Now I have this code which uses the above structure:

```
  BaseController baseContr;

   Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.load("some inputstream to config.properties");

    Constructor cons = Class.forName( prop.getProperty( keyProperty ) ).
    getConstructor( Class.forName( prop.getProperty( keyProperty ) ).getClass() );// keyProperty is some input string from user
   ( ( XXXXXX )cons.newInstance ( new Car(....) )  ).execute();
```

Where you see `XXXXXX` is actually where I want a way to put type cast dynamically. This casting must find a way to invoke the `execute()` method in either `AddCarController` or     `GetCarController`
   I do not want to use either one of the implementations of BaseController dirrectly to invoke method, but rather, have a way to cast it based on what `prop.getProperty(keyProperty)` gives...

Comment: Why are you not just casting to the interface? Once you've constructed the instance, you know it implements the interface and you can just call execute, right?

Comment: At Runtime Java will invoke the `execute()` method in the implementation, but in the `Interface`. But at compile time it wont .... wait, let me see... I will comment back soon... I wanna try it out

Comment: I have just tried it out... it does not work.

you know, Java cannot execute a method in the base class/interface/abstract, but it is only during Compile time when it checks for consistency in both base and child class

Comment: "it does not work" is *never, ever, ever* enough information. There *is* no implementation in the interface. The whole point of an interface is to provide something for callers to call without knowing about the implementation. It really will work.

Comment: if I have something like this:

`InterfaceLevel interf = newInstanceOfImplementation;
      interf.executeMethodInImplementation()`

does not work based on polymorphism rules. because the compiler has to know where to find the the method in which implementation class

Comment: You're wrong. That compiles and works just fine. Compiler knows `InstanceOfImplementation` perfectly. See my answer.

Comment: @kholofelo: No, it really doesn't, assuming the interface includes the declaration for the method you want to call. I think you've misunderstood how polymorphism in general and interfaces in particular work in Java.

Comment: Jon is right. Just do the following `Controller controller = cons.newInstance ( new Car(....) ) ; controller.execute() ;` The appropriate implementation of `execute` will be invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing how polymorphism works. If you would need to know the exact class to cast to, that would completely the defeat the whole purpose of polymorphism.

Even if you cast to `BaseController` -or the interface, as pointed out by Jon Skeet, which in fact is more correct-, the instance will remain a `AddCarController` or `GetCarController` instance, and calling `execute()` in this instance will call the `AddCarController#execute()` or `GetCarController#execute()`, and **never** `BaseController#execute()`.

Here's an example on this behavior:

```
class A {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from class A");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from class B");
    }
}

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws OperationNotSupportedException
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final A a = new B();
        a.hello();
    }
}
```

Prints `"Hello from class B"` as exepected.

---

**EDIT**: A more detailed example using reflection and interface:

```
class A implements I {

    @Override
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from class A");
    }
}

class B implements I {

    @Override
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from class B");
    }
}

interface I {
    public void hello();
}

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     * @throws OperationNotSupportedException
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        I i = (I) Class.forName("A").newInstance();
        i.hello();
        i = (I) Class.forName("B").newInstance();
        i.hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that I can understand, but the problem is that I want to do this:
`A a = (someImplementation) b`

in which 'someImplementation' is found out through reflection/dynamically

Comment: Again, you don't need to find `someImplementation` by reflection. `b` should be the object instance you created by reflection already, and should be the right type. Use fixed `someInterface` instead of `someImplementation`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think it's me who can't explain my problem properly... but given your code above, what if we do not know the className of your implementation, but rather, we know that anything that implements the interface MUST implement the "execute" method...

so we do not know that the name of the Implementation is `B`...

Comment: So you're given an object instance you don't know what type it is but you know what interface it implements? Do I understand right? If so, you cast it to the interface. See my last example.

Comment: Yes  yes yes,
in this one :
` i = (I) Class.forName("B").newInstance();` we know that its type is `I`, but in my came I dont even know if it is `I` or `J`

Comment: `I` **is an interface**, not a class. You don't know `Controller` interface? There's only one interface in your question...

Comment: I know `Controller interface` , and I know `BaseController implements Controller` but is is `abstract` so I cant instantiate it on `BaseController` nor can I do so on `Controller interface`...

so I have to cast it to some implementation `'x'` which can differ...

so I do not know the name of `x`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28259/discussion-between-m0skit0-and-kholofelo)